# get and set an text element in a table with a script in indesign

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I was looking about indesign scripts and I have not found anything about this topic, which I think is important. So here it is my question:
 - How to modify a text frame in a table in Indesign CS6 with JavaScript ?

I have try something like this instruction :

```
app.activeWindow.activePage.textFrames[0];
```

but this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Pages usually have a text frame, which contains a table. Tables must be anchored within a text frame as far as I know. If there was a text frame also within that table, then you would need something like this to access it:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

doc.pages[0].textFrames[0].tables[0].textFrames[0];
```

In other words, you would need to reference text frame twice. One for the text frame which contains the table and another for the text frame *within* the table.

Answer (score 0):

Table objects cannot contain TextFrame objects in InDesign.
Tables do contain Cells.
Cells contain Texts.
A Text object can contain a TextFrame. In such a case it would be an anchored or inline text frame.
So, if there really does happen to be a text frame anchored to some text inside a table, you would access it as follows (let's say in this case that the user has a table selected in the UI before running the script, and that the 7th cell in the table contains an anchored text frame):

```
app.selection[0].cells[6].texts[0].textFrames[0];
```

That would return the first TextFrame in that cell.

However, this is a fairly unusual situation.
 There is not usually much point in anchoring a text frame to a cell, since cells themselves can contain any text needed.